# Java - Calculate mean of numbers that are lower than 60 while disregarding numbers greater than or equal to 60

Tags: math, numbers, average, mean, continue

I am trying to calculate the mean of numbers (that are less than 60) which the user inputs. But I can't get my program to disregard any numbers greater or equal to 60. Have I used the "continue" statement incorrectly? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter a number: ");
    double n = userInput.nextInt();


    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        if (n >=60){
            continue;
        }
        count++;
        sum += n;
        System.out.printf("Enter a number: ");
        n = userInput.nextInt();
    }


    System.out.println("Average of numbers is: " + (sum / count));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code results in an infinite loop, since `continue;` immediately jumps to `while` which then hits `continue` again since `n` isn't changed and this continues indefinitely. Instead, let the user input the number *before* deciding whether to skip that iteration. This also means that we might input 0 so let us break free from the loop on that condition inside the loop instead. (Opinions on whether `while(true)` is good practice may differ, but here it's just as safe as your original code.)

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
double n = 0;

int count = 0;
double sum = 0;

while (true) {
    System.out.printf("Enter a number: ");
    n = userInput.nextInt();

    if (n >= 60) {
        continue;
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        break;
    }

    count++;
    sum += n;
}


System.out.println("Average of numbers is: " + (sum / count));
```